# What is this component, is this a microphone?

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I was researching projects and I saw a PCB. I am wondering what is this component. I don't know what it is so I want to ask you, what is this component? Is this a microphone?
I am asking about this big white thing.

[image]

Top side:

Bottom side:

[image]

Another PCB design, again they say they use microphone.

Comment: What does the PCB do? Doesn't look like a microphone or a speaker to me.

Comment: I thought it is a microphone because they say they are processing sound. I added full PCB on question.

Comment: A view from a bit further away would help. The photos are so close it's hard to see the 3D structure of the part.

Comment: I added one more photo.

Comment: Please add a photo taken from a side angle so we can see how tall it is and what is underneath it.

Comment: AnalogKid, I don't have photo. Only I have these. Sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a light guide, a piece of plastic that is intended to be illuminated by a LED.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought it is a microphone because they say they are processing sound. I added full PCB on question.